# Unable to initiate cronjob in strongloop

Tags: node.js, cron, strongloop

I have to run cron job in strongloop, for that i was installed "cron" using command " npm install cron".

In root=>server=>boot directory, i created cron.js with below code.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {

    console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

I don't no, where i had mistake, my code was not executing.

Please guide me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: where did you run `npm install cron`? it should be in the same directory of cron.js

Comment: I was run in root directory and module placed in node_modules.

Comment: so what's the error you get? That code should work fine without any problem.

Comment: cron.js not initiated after i start server(slc run).

Comment: What if you run it as `node cron.js`?

Comment: When i execute "node cron.js" i am getting exception.module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/qualian/workspaces/ruiboy/cron.js'

Comment: Thanks for your help. I placed my js in root directory earlier. Now i moved to /server/boot. Now cron working successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no issues in my example at https://github.com/superkhau/sandbox/tree/so32410263. Try it out and let me know if you're still running into issues.